# encryption with python

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

If I want to use:

```
recip = M2Crypto.RSA.load_pub_key(open('recipient_public_key.pem','rb').read())
```

Then how will it retrieve the key? What will recip will print?

I need to get the public key of the recipient from the server(open key server) and for that first I need to store the key on server.

Answer (score 0):

check what public_key.pem returns .clear this how you want to recognize your recipient .